# Получить первый и последний день месяца

Tags: java, android

Как получить первый и последний день любого месяца? На активити есть кнопка `Next`, нажимая на которую в `TextView` будет выводится текст первый и последний день месяца.

Пытался сделать следующим образом, но неправильно считается

```
private void setMonthNext() {

    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); 
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    mills1 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;

    txtPeriod.setText(calendar.getTime() + " ");

    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);

    txtPeriod.append(calendar.getTime() + "");

    mills2 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
}
```

Comment: Что именно нужно получить? День недели? И где в коде предположительно делается?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22239895/5621869

Comment: LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1); LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(LocalDate.now().lengthOfMonth()); - перый и последний день текущего месяца

Comment: Нужно в итоге выводить в TextView текст типа 01.01.2020 - 31.01.2020 (и так для каждого месяца) при листании вперед, а также получать timestamp первого и последнего дня месяца.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

```
YearMonth month = YearMonth.now();
String firstDay = month.atDay(1).toString(),
endDay = month.atEndOfMonth().toString();

System.out.println(firstDay);
System.out.println(endDay);
```

Вывод:

> 2020-01-01
>   2020-01-31

А вообще, вариантов очень много.

**Вариант 2:**

```
LocalDate initial = LocalDate.now(),
firstDay = initial.withDayOfMonth(1),
endDay = initial.withDayOfMonth(initial.lengthOfMonth());
Timestamp firstTimeStamp = Timestamp.valueOf(firstDay.atStartOfDay()),
endTimeStamp = Timestamp.valueOf(endDay.atStartOfDay());

System.out.println(firstDay + ": " + firstTimeStamp.getTime());
System.out.println(endDay + ": " + endTimeStamp.getTime());
```

Вывод:

```
2020-01-01: 1577800800000   
2020-01-31: 1580392800000
```

**Вариант 3:**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date firstDay = cal.getTime();
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
Date endDay = cal.getTime();

System.out.println(firstDay.toString() + ": " + firstDay.getTime());
System.out.println(endDay.toString() + ": " + endDay.getTime());
```

Вывод:

> Sat Jan 11 22:51:04 VLAT 2020: 1578747064996
>   Fri Jan 31 22:51:04 VLAT 2020: 1580475064996

Comment: Это работает только с API 26.

Comment: И еще мне нужно не только вывести, но и получить timestamp этих дат.

Comment: А как при нажатии на кнопку Next получить следующий месяц?

Comment: В ваших ответах только текущий месяц можно получить.

Comment: @Kolhoznik,Ответ на вопрос есть, в чем проблема добавить любую дату?! Через `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);` Или вобоще, просто взять и сразу выставить нужную дату `cal.set(2019,Calendar.JUNE, 22) ;`.

Comment: Данное Активити будет использоваться для отображения списка по различным фильтрам. В частности пользователь выберет фильтр месяц и в textview отобразиться первый и последний день текущего месяца, далее нажмет кнопку next и отобразиться первый и последний день следующего месяца и т.д.

Comment: А можно ли использовать метод getActualMaximum, для реализации такого же перехода по неделям?

Comment: @Kolhoznik, не совсем поняло, что вы хотите... Вам проще задать новый вопрос. тут принято задавать 1 вопрос и получать ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть календарь, то

-первый день месяца всегда 1;
-последний день месяца:

```
calendar.getActualMaximum( Calendar.DATE );
```