# Как получить кол-во дней в месяце? Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Я получаю дату с помощью `DateTime.now()`. Как мне дальше получить текущий месяц и дальше кол-во дней в нём?

Как получить месяц понятно: `DateTime.now().monthOfYear`. Но вот как быть с кол-вом дней в нём?

Comment: что за DateTime? Joda, что ли?

Comment: Kotlin-то какой? JVM, Android? Уточняйте всегда платформу.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja  в метках был андроид, я удалил, потому что ничего специфически андроидного вроде бы тут нет

Comment: @Эникейщик, Котлин мультплатформенный (JVM/JS/Native). Поди догадайся что DateTime не портировали куда. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получить первый и последний день месяца](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1068526/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val daysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для `Java 8+` или `Android API 26+` доступен новый пакет `java.time`

```
// Get the number of days in that month
val yearMonthObject = YearMonth.of(1999, 2)
val daysInMonth = yearMonthObject.lengthOfMonth() //28
```

Comment: c [desugar](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) можно и с API 21+